# Showing $\int_a^{a+T}f(x) dx=\int_0^T f(x)dx$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$

Tags: integration

$\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$ ,

$$\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{T} f(x) dx.$$

$f(x)$ is periodic function.

Comment: Make a change of variable $t=x-a.$

Comment: What is the period ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One semi-intuitive way of showing this (in part) - it glosses over some of the specific details, but I think it's a useful way of thinking about these things, occasionally.

**Claim:** $$\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{T} f(x) dx$$

**Proof:** Let $g(a)=\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx$. Then, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\frac{dg}{da}=f(a+T)-f(a)$, which is equal to $0$ by the $T$-periodicity of $f$. Hence $g$ is constant, and equal to $g(0)$, i.e. $\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{T} f(x) dx$ for all $a$, as desired.

**Remark:** The reason this is a bit quicker, but also a bit less rigorous, is that it tacitly makes some assumptions about $f$ in claiming that $g$ ought to be differentiable. This will certainly be true if $f$ is continuous (even piecewise continuous), and will tend to be true in most concrete applications, but is not generally true if we only assume $f$ to be periodic. Still, I think this method is a worthwhile perspective, and is, if nothing else, a pretty neat way of confirming that this result behaves as we might expect it to, under "nice" conditions.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is $T$-periodic, then $f(t+T)=f(t)$.  Now, note that we can write

$$\int_a^{a+T}f(t)\,dt=\int_a^0 f(t)\,dt+\int_0^T f(t)\,dt+\int_T^{T+a} f(t)\,dt \tag 1$$

Enforcing the substitution $t\to t+T$ in the third integral of $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}\int_a^{a+T}f(t)\,dt&=\int_a^0 f(t)\,dt+\int_0^T f(t)\,dt+\int_0^{a} f(t+T)\,dt\\\\&= \int_a^0 f(t)\,dt+\int_0^T f(t)\,dt+\int_0^{a} f(t)\,dt\\\\&=\int_0^T f(t)\,dt
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!